# How to make a registred domain name point to an IP address?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, vps, nameserver

I bought a domain name with A Small Orange.

Next, I bought a VPS with SoftsysHosting.

The VPS is running Windows Server 2008 R2 and I would like to know, how to make people who visit my domain, go to my IP address.

I understand something about nameservers, but not the specifics of what kind of setup I need to do.

Do I need to install a DNS server on my VPS and add a record for that domain name; then in my ASmallOrange dashboard insert the ip of my DNS server as the name server?

Any guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: Two downvotes: Is this in the wrong stackexchange site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't unless you want to manage the domain on your own DNS server. Otherwise you just can manage it from the controlpanel where you bought the domain.

Comment: To expand on this answer and how it helped. All  I had to was go into my control panel where my domain was bought and set the IP where that domain is pointing; in this case the static IP for my VPS.